# How to view Esri GRID format file in wxpython file browse window?

Tags: raster, file-formats, esri-grid-format, browser

I'm trying to browse for all kinds of vector and raster data using a filebrowsebutton.

The problem is I don't know how to let the browse window see the Esri **GRID** files (which contains a folder and a bunch of other files in a Windows standard file browser window) as a **single** file just as the ArcGIS tools see it, so that I can load it in by clicking on it.

I searched through the internet but didn't find any discussion on it. I know how to write code to access a specific GRID file, but not through a file browser.

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Below are my codes about the filebrowsebutton:

```
wildcard = "Shapefiles (.shp)|*.shp|" \
               "Raster files (GRID, .img, .tif, .bmp, .gif, .jp2, .jpg, .png)|*; *.img; *.tif; *.bmp; *.gif; *.jp2; *.jpg; *.png|" \
               "All files (*.*)|*.*"

    self.fileBrowseButton1 = wx.lib.filebrowsebutton.FileBrowseButton(buttonText='Browse',
          dialogTitle='Choose a file', fileMask= wildcard,
          id=wxID_FRAME1FILEBROWSEBUTTON1, initialValue='',
          labelText=u'Locate the GIS dataset:', parent=self,
          pos=wx.Point(40, 80), size=wx.Size(496, 40), startDirectory=u'.',
          style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL,
          toolTip='Type filename or click browse to choose file')
```

Comment: If you know how to access a specific GRID dataset (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid), then you know that it can be referred to by means of the directory in which all its component datasets reside.